# AlarmManager not working, delays schedule task

Tags: android, scheduled-tasks, alarmmanager, scheduler

I am working on scheduler application where I ask user time using Calendar dialog. Then I schedule task using AlarmManager you can see the code below.

```
    Log.d("SchedulerTag", "sendMessageLater: " + new Date(timeInMillis));
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("message", message_string);
    intent.putExtra("number", end_number);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message Scheduled Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message Scheduled Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

After this, I receive it using AlarmReceiver class, the code

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //some code her
}
```

The problem is, the task is not scheduling at the right time it gets only called after 10 minutes no matter what time has been chosen

My manifest contains the receiver. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JobScheduler for repeating task.

```
ComponentName serviceComponent = new ComponentName(context, TestJobService.class);
JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(15, serviceComponent);
builder.setMinimumLatency(500);
builder.setPersisted(true);

JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)context.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
if (jobScheduler != null) {
    jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
}
```

TestJobService.class

public class TestJobService extends JobService {

```
@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    // do your code when job scheduler fires.
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: where exactly I need to put the date here?

Comment: calculate milliseconds till now and set milliseconds into minimum latency method.

Comment: It's for API 21 I also need low API support